# How to find the limit $\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n^{n/2}}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Some words about сonvergence rate:

$$\\log^{\beta}(n) \to n^a \to a^n \to n! \to n^n$$
$$\ n \to \infty$$

But I can't find place for 
$$\ n^{n/2} $$

Exactly the question is how to find the limit:
$$\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n^{n/2}}$$

Comment: Is there any condition on $a$?

Comment: @SahibaArora The limit is independent of $a$.

Comment: Note that for any finite $a$ we have $|n|>|a|$ for large enough $n$. Therefore the denominator will become arbitrarily larger than the numerator.

Comment: It seems that during the solving condition will appear.

Comment: Find the Log of the limit which becomes
n(log a - log(n/2))
which clearly goes to -infinity as n goes to Infinity
Therefore the given limit is zero

a must be strictly positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^{n/2}}$.

By Cauchy-Hadamard it is easy to see that this power series has radius of convergence $r=\infty$.

Hence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^{n/2}}$

converges for all $x$. This gives

$\ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a^n}{n^{n/2}}=0$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>(a+1)^2$, you have $$n^\frac{n}{2} = (n^{\frac12})^n > |a+1|^n$$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that  for all $n\geq 4|a|^2$, we have that $2|a|\leq \sqrt{n}$ which imples
$$0\leq \left|\frac{a^n}{n^{n/2}}\right|=\left(\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$$
then use the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Make a change: $n=2m$. Note: $m\to+\infty \Rightarrow \frac{2m}{a^2} \to+\infty$. Then:
$$\ \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{a^n}{n^{n/2}}=\ \lim_{m \to +\infty}\frac{a^{2m}}{(2m)^{m}}=\ \lim_{m \to +\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2m}{a^2}\right)^m}=0.$$